# how to do remote access in virtualbox (configure as bridge) with ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, virtualbox, remote-access, forwarding

I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 in a VirtualBox set up as Bridge.

> ipv4: 192.168.55.226

> ipv6: 2804:389:a09c:d31a:a00:27ff:feca:3cad

How do I remote access my virtualBox by ipv6?

> 2804:389:a09c:d31a:a00:27ff:feca:3cad

Answer (score 0):

Add a DNS name with that IP, allow it through any firewall, and remote into it. Probably via ssh. That's it, just normal IP routing.

Confirm the IP address is not temporary. ff:fe in the host part implies EUI-64 based on layer 2 address, which should be stable.